# Upload newer version of android app to admin console

Tags: android

I am trying to update the newly built apk to google admin console for organization internal use. I already had an older version I just want to upload a new build to replace that old version. It seems like google doesn't allow that as it said app with the same package name already exist. Then I try to delete that old one and re-upload the new one, but Google doesn't seem to allow deleting the uploaded app.

Any guide to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You just need to upload your .aab fie in internal testing track. You can get more information [from here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

if you upload an app you never delete or change package name you just change the update app on same package name.